# Laravel - defining the right relationship

Tags: laravel

**User Table:** has `zone_id` field in it.

**Zones table:** has `world_id` field in it.

- Each user can be in one zone, for example, **zone_id = 1**
- Each zone belongs to one world, for example - **world_id = 5**

My desired output is returning user zone and world info.

This is how I can make it without any relationship set:

```
$zone = Zone::find($user->zone_Id);
$world = World::find($zone->world_id);
$data = $user;
$data['zone'] = $zone;
$data['zone']['world'] = $world;
```

My question is.. I'm sure relationship can be used for a cleaner code, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

1. Should I stick with the current code or define a relationship?
2. If the answer for 1 is **define a relationship**, Any help of what's the right relationship between these 3 models?

Solution 1:

```
`public function getZone(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->input('token');
        $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
        // Simplest example using relationships
        $userWithZone = User::with('zone.world')->find($user->id); // You'll get the `zone` relationship info here, too
        return $userWithZone;
    }`
```

Error: `returns "Call to a member function getQuery() on null"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can achieve this with Eloquent Relationships.

```
// User.php
class User
{
    public function zone()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Zone::class);
    }
}

// Zone.php
class Zone
{
    public function world()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(World::class);
    }
}
```

Simplest example using relationships

```
$user = User::with('zone.world')->find($id); // You'll get the `zone` relationship info here, too
```

You can get more complex with your relationships if you want

```
$user = User::with(['zone' => function($query) {
    $query->with('world')
          ->select('id', 'zone_name', 'world_id');
})->select('username', 'zone_id')->find($id);
```

or even...

```
$user = User::with(['zone' => function($query) {
    $query->with(['world' => function($query2) {
        $query2->select('id', 'world_name');
    }])->select('id', 'zone_name', 'world_id');
})->select('username', 'zone_id')->find($id);
```

Your resulting `$user` will look something like:

```
'user' => [ // This is a Collection
    'username',
    'email',
    'zone_id',
    'zone' => [ // This is a Collection
        'id',
        'zone_name',
        'world_id',
        'world' => [ // This is a Collection
            'id',
            'world_name'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: I have an error trying your first solution, i have updated my question with the info

Comment: See my update. I was missing `return` in the relationships.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you update your initial question?